# Saving deleted records to another table

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I am deleting records from one table (based on a condition) like :

```
procedure TForm3.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if MessageDlg('Are you sure???' , mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
    Abort else
Case cxRadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
0: begin
with Form1.ABSQuery1 do begin
Form1.ABSQuery1.Close;
Form1.ABSQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.ABSQuery1.SQL.Text :='delete from LOG where status="YES" ';
Form1.ABSQuery1.ExecSQL;
Form1.ABSTable1.Refresh;
end;
end;
End;
end;
```

However,I want to save these deleted records in another table that I have created for the purpose (LOG_ARCHIVE) which is identical to the LOG table. So how do I save these deleted records over there ?

Comment: Use the trigger, Luke.

Comment: @Abelisto: According to the Absolute Database [documentation](http://www.componentace.com/search/?query_string=create+trigger&x=0&y=0), there's no trigger support (at least a search on `triggers` and `create trigger` both don't return anything about them).

Comment: @KenWhite: Sorry, it is because of my carelessness. Instead of the "ABSQuery" I read "ADOQuery" :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using a database that supported it, you could use a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger. However, according to a search on the [Absolute Database documentation](http://www.componentace.com/search/?query_string=create%20trigger&x=0&y=0), there's no support for `CREATE TRIGGER` and a search on `triggers` at the same site returns nothing about them either.

The lack of trigger support probably just leaves you with performing an `INSERT` into the other table first, before doing the `DELETE` from your `LOG` table. According to the [documentation again](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/insertstatement.htm), a query is able to be used as the source of data for an `INSERT` (see the second example on the linked page). This means you can do something like this:

```
ABSQuery1.SQL.Text := 'insert into LOG_ARCHIVE'#13 +
                           '(select * from LOG where status = ''Yes'')';
ABSQuery1.SQL.ExecSQL;
ABSQuery1.Close;

{ 
  No need to use SQL.Clear here. Setting the SQL.Text replaces
  what was there before with new text.
}
ABSQuery1.SQL.Text :='delete from LOG where status=''YES''';
ABSQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

You really should wrap this entire operation in a [transaction](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/transactions.htm) ([Delphi example here](http://www.componentace.com/transaction-delphi.htm)), so that in case something fails both the `INSERT` and `DELETE` can be undone. (For instance, if the `INSERT` works putting the rows in the `LOG_ARCHIVE` file, but the `DELETE` then fails for some reason, you have no way to remove the rows you inserted into the archive file.) A transaction can be started before you do the `INSERT`, rolled back if it (or the `DELETE` fails or committed if both of them succeed.

Comment: +1 possibly the downvoter did not agree with (the status = "YES" is invalid SQL syntax). With a poor design an status as varchar it might work.

Comment: @bummi: Thanks. :-) I'd remove it, but I don't think it's wrong; I can't think of any SQL DB that would allow that even as a VARCHAR with poor design.

Comment: @KenWhite Try a simple test with MySQL (as one of any) ... using "" is valid

Comment: @SirRufo: OK. That's one exception (MySQL, which is a great example of not being compliant with standards). :-) I don't see any indication that ABS supports that in their documentation. I'll remove that mention from my question, though, since you did indeed show me a single DBMS that supported it. :-) In *real* DBs, "YES" would return a constant value for a `SELECT`, as in `SELECT "Y" AS MARRIED, "STUPID" AS Intelligence FROM MYTable". It isn't allowed as the condition of a where statement in SQL Server, for instance, or even the much smaller Advantage Database Server. MySQL is a poor example.

Comment: A few comments: `ABSQuery -> ABSQuery1`; I also don't think `ABSQuery1.Close` is needed. a Transaction is must here IMHO (if the ABS DB supports it).

Comment: @kobik: The poster didn't ask about how to use a transaction, and there's none in the original question. The `Close` was included also because it was in the original code. The question here was how to keep a copy of rows before they were deleted, not a tutorial on properly writing database applications. I answered the question asked. :-) Thanks for the catch on the missing `1` - I missed it.

Comment: You *did* remove the `SQL.Clear` that was originally in the question :) And I still think [Transactions](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/transactions.htm) is worth mentioning for this particular task, because otherwise it may lead to data corruption if the `delete` statement fails.

Comment: The `SQL.Clear` in the original question was totally wasted. I don't know what the poster wants to do here, so I'll let them decide whether the `Close` is needed or not. I'll add a note about transactions, since they are supported by ADB, and add a link to the example on their site.

Comment: I find it a good practice to always clear the SQL text of a query before using it especially if the query gets used more than once. Just in case ...Also I do not get what's wrong with (status = "YES") syntax ?

Comment: I will see how to wrap this thing in a transaction like ken suggested... Thank you all ....

Comment: `status = "YES"` is not standard SQL. If ADB allows it, it's fine. If you could someday change to a more standards-compliant DBMS like SQL Server, it will fail. From SQL Server Books OnLine `WHERE` example: `SELECT ProductID, Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name = 'Blade'` - see the single quotes instead of double?

Comment: Just checked to make sure, and according to the [ADB docs](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/selectstatement.htm) their syntax is single-quotes too: `SELECT * FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE '%men%'`

Comment: It's Delphi that wont let me use single quotes. If I use single quotes (status = 'YES') then it wont compile. Also I am a little perplexed about using transaction. First I archive the events and then delete them. If any of them fails I end up with orphans. If I archive and then deletion fails, I end up later with possible double entries in the archive.